# VS Code integrated terminal shows Qt incompatibility when matplotlib script is run

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Every time I tried to run a Python script containing matplotlib in VSCode, I receive the following message in the integrated terminal:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.14.1) with this library (5.15.2)
```

Runing script from VSCode:

[image: Runing script from VSCode]

If I run the script directy from the terminal outside VSCode, the script is running fine.

Runing script from terminal:

[image: Runing script from terminal]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed `PyQt5` packages? If it is, could you try to uninstall or reinstall it?

Comment: Hi @Steven_MSFT . Upgrading `PyQt5` and `pyQt5-qt5` packages,  updating VSCode, and restarting the PC solved the issue. Thanks.